# How do I run Boot Camp Assistant on a partition on an external drive?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, bootcamp, partition, external-disk

I've partitioned my external HD and I want to install Windows 10 on it using Boot Camp Assistant. When I open Boot Camp Assistant, it shows my whole Hard Drive, not my partition.
[image: Disk Utility]
[image: Boot Camp Assistant]
I've got the Windows 10 ISO file and I've formatted the partition to MS-DOS (FAT32).

Comment: I think you're confusing the steps. Your second screenshot ("Create Bootable USB Drive for Windows Installation" talks about creating the bootable media, not where it installs windows. You'll need an empty USB drive to create the bootable media and then boot from that - you'll then go through the usual windows installation steps.

Comment: @KevinGrabher I want to put it on a partition on my USB drive.

Comment: Not possible with Bootcamp assistant.

Comment: @KevinGrabher Then how do I do it?

Comment: I believe the installer would need to be on a drive with an MBR partition table which would require reformatting the drive. So on an existing GUID-drive? I don't think there is a way to do it.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I think I've got a solution.